# How to find the element which has the biggest order in finite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups

> Here $\mathbb{Z}$ is the integer ring and let $G$ denote the multipli9 group which has inverse in multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}/200\mathbb{Z}$ (so $G$ is the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}/200\mathbb{Z}$). Find the element which has biggest order in $G$.

$G$ is  abelian and finite. I only need to find the element whose order are coprime. But it very hard for me to do this. I get the order of $\overline 3$ in $G$ by computer.

How can we find the element by hand? Could someone give some details?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea where exactly you're struggling, we can help you better. ^_^

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem. Otherwise it looks like you are asking others to do your homework for you.

Comment: You need the Carmichael function : $\lambda(200)=20$. $3$ is one of the elements doing the job.

Comment: How to calculate the order of 3 by hand instead of computer.

Comment: How can I calculate the order of 3?

Comment: Is there another element that its order is 20? Why 20 is the biggest order ?

Comment: Read the wikipedia article about the "Carmichael function" for more details. To see that the order for $3$ is in fact $20$, you only have to compute $3^{10}\mod 200$ and $3^4\mod 200$ since the order must be a divisor of $20$. For the first, you can calculate $3^5\mod 200$ and square it. $13$ and $17$ do the job as well, but here calculation by hand is more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!